# How do I import a spice model into LT spice?

Tags: ltspice, spice, modeling

I decided to create a question of how to import models into LT spice since there were questions that are related but no definitive guide on how to import 3rd party models on this site. There are many ways to do this, post your favorite method

How do I import a 3rd party spice model into LT spice?

Comment: There are at least a couple bits and pieces: [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/251506/38098) and [that one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/338654/38098). Nothing comprehensive here, though. That would take some serious writing, I think.

Comment: There are two cases- subckt and if the model is pre-existing (like a diode, say).

Comment: Good point, I'll edit the answer unless someone else wants to come up with a more comprehensive one.

Comment: By the way, for those downvoting, SE encourages this sort of thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is possible in LTspice IV to create a new symbol from scratch for a
>   third-party model but who has the time? Follow these easy steps to
>   generate a new symbol for a third-party model defined in a subcircuit
>   (.SUBCKT statement).
>
> 1. Open the netlist file that contains the subcircuit definitions in LTspice (File > Open or drag file into LTspice)
> 2. Right-click the line containing the name of the subcircuit, and select Create Symbol:
> 3. Edit the symbol if needed and save.
>
> To use the new symbol (and associated third party model) in a
>   schematic, select the symbol from the AutoGenerated directory in the
>   component library (F2) and place it in your schematic

Source: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html

Comment: If its autogenerated then its not portable right? How is that done?

Comment: If you want to port that model to another LT spice program, you need to get the .asy and ..lib files (one is for the symbol the other for the model) and copy them to their respective folders .

Answer (score 3):

Analog Devices has a well-hidden but quite useful web page on how to associate an existing device symbol to a down-loaded spice model. The URL is https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html.

I've used this (for example) to import an IGBT model and associate it with the quite nice IGBT symbol in LTSpice. I've also used it to be able to model the TL072 model from T.I. with the "generic" op-amp symbol in LTSpice.

Now if Analog Devices would just make it easier to share LTSpice design files with collaborators...

Comment: Better than TI, it's really hard to move she if thier models around