# Help me to resolve this error in this LTSpice Simulation

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, amplifier, ltspice, spice

Below is LTspice simulation in which this error occurs.

The error is `Unknown subcircuit called inc xu1 n001 n003 op opamp`

How do I fix this error?

[image: LTspice simulation]

Comment: With no partnumber on the schematic shown, are you sure you applied a model to the opamp? If you used one of the Generic/Universal models, you may have to specify the actual opamp characteristics, or supply a component spice model before the simulation can run

Answer (score 3):

You have no model for the opamp, every component needs a model:

add the line `.lib opamp.sub` for further reading on adding models see these links

https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html

[How do I import a spice model into LT spice?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/435633/how-do-i-import-a-spice-model-into-lt-spice)